# .NET Core as Windows Service and service start timeout

Tags: .net-core, windows-services, asp.net-core-6.0

We are using simple windows service

```
        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.AddConfiguration(Configuration);
            cfg.Build().BindConfigurations();
        })
        .UseSerilog()
        .UseWindowsService()
        .Build();
    host.Run();
```

This is working great. The issues is that whenever Windows restart, we see the schedular could not start because of this reason,

```
A timeout was reached (30000 milliseconds) while waiting for the OurScheduler service to connect.
```

How can we avoid this error. As this making our choice of .NET Core as background job risky.

Comment: Have you taken a look at this? [timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1986292/a-timeout-was-reached-while-waiting-for-the-service-to-connect-error-after-reb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a watcher(`.bat` file) in Task schedular that will make that the job is running if not then start the job,

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('sc query MyWindowsServiceJobName ^| findstr STATE') do set _CmdResult=%%a
if "%_CmdResult%"=="%_CmdResult:RUNNING=%" (
    SC START MyWindowsServiceJobName
)
```